# Sort a vector of wstrings, but case insensitive

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

When sorting a vector of `wstring`s with:

```
vector<wstring> v; 
v.push_back(L"zzz"); 
v.push_back(L"BBB"); 
v.push_back(L"aaa"); 
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

the result is BBB, aaa, zzz. **How to make a case insensitive sort instead?**

---

I tried with

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), 
       [](wstring lhs, wstring rhs) { return tolower(lhs) < tolower(rhs); });
```

but without any success because `tolower` works only with char / wchar_t, and not with a wstring.

I might have to use [`lexicographical_compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare) but I don't see how.

(As I'm looking for an efficient sorting, able to do it on millions of wstrings in a short time, I thought that temporarily storing a copy of all wstrings lowercase, and sorting this 2nd vector wouldn't be a good idea?)

Comment: [`std::towlower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/towlower)

Comment: As you are using Unicode can you define case insensitive for Unicode "characters" ?  (note it's not a 1 <--> 1 mapping outside the ASCII set)

Comment: @0x5453 already tried with this, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but without any success because tolower works only char / wchar_t.

You want [`std::ctype<wchar_t>::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype/tolower):

```
auto& f = use_facet<ctype<wchar_t>>(locale());
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [&f](wstring const& a, wstring const& b) {
    return lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), [&f](wchar_t ai, wchar_t bi) {
        return f.tolower(ai) < f.tolower(bi);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, instead of `std::ctype<wchar_t>::tolower` you may like to use [`towlower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/towlower) that uses the current (global) `C` locale.

Comment: Thanks! I can't make it work for now, can you paste the full line `std::sort(....);`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Basj Added an example of `sort` invocation for you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to think on it a few minutes, why a double implementation of a comparison? Once with lexicographical_compare, the other with ... < ... ?

Comment: @Basj `lexicographical_compare` compares strings symbol-wise with a comparison function that lowercases symbols before comparing them.

Comment: Oh ok I see! Last detail: can I avoid locale()? I'm ok with a not-100% perfect sort (in the case of non-ascii characters). I would prefer very fast compare than a slower compare with locale.

Comment: @Basj You may like to benchmark it against a non-portable `wcscasecmp` or whatever you have available on your platform. Also, have a look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/ilexicographical_compare.html.

Comment: It seems to work without `auto &f = ...` and just: `sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](wstring const& a, wstring const& b) {
  return lexicographical_compare(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), [&](wchar_t ai, wchar_t bi) {
   return tolower(ai) < tolower(bi);
  });
 });` (with tolower, and not towlower (which I benchmarked much slower)).

Comment: @Basj [`tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower): _If the value of ch is not representable as unsigned char and does not equal EOF, the behavior is undefined_. In other words, C-style `tolower` only works on `char`. Try [`towlower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/towlower) instead.

Comment: Yes @MaximEgorushkin, but with `tolower` I get an average 800ms sorting time (in a benchmark situation that would be too long to describe here), then the same code with `towlower` gave me 5500ms sorting time...

Comment: @Basj `::tolower` does not work for characters above `0xff`, mate. Here is a demonstration http://ideone.com/LQzac7. On Linux `::tolower` returns the original character in this case, i.e. it does nothing. `::towlower` does the right thing.

Comment: Then it's perfect for my use case if it returns the original character. As it's a real time app, I prefer a 6x faster behaviour (even if that would sometimes not sort some non-ascii strings). Thanks for the code demonstration!

Comment: By the way, what's the difference between `::tolower` and `std::tolower` in your code demo? I notice you have put `std::` for towlower but not for tolower, is there a reason?

Comment: @Basj Removed `std::`, it was overlooked.

Comment: @Basj Still, passing anything but `char` into `::tolower` results in undefined behaviour. The C standard says so and so does Linux manpage.

Comment: I looked at Boost's `ilexicographical_compare` source code and it uses `lexicographical_compare` with [`is_iless`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/is_iless.html) which itself uses `std::toupper<T1>(Arg1,m_Loc) < std::toupper<T2>(Arg2,m_Loc)`, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/boost/algorithm/string/compare.hpp). What kind of toupper is it? Is it the standard std::toupper? Or std::towupper? Another version of it?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Is this safe to use with wstring containing characters which are only english alphabets or it is not and it depends on the locale?

Comment: @SolidMercury You should make your question a question, rather than a comment.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin My question is w.r.t the answer you have posted. It seems be an interesting thing to ask as I was exploring the locale and wstring representation.

Comment: @SolidMercury Answer to your question: yes.